# Python: appending to numpy array at certain indexes and change shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
print(pred_galactic_prob.shape)
print(pred_galactic_prob[0:3])

(465, 5)
[[0.05 0.94 0.3  0.01 0.5 ]
 [0.01 0.02 0.01 0.85 0.11]
 [0.03 0.95 0.3  0.3  0.02]]
```

I want to append to this and change the shape so there are 13 columns and it would look like this:

```
[[0.05 0.   0.94 0.   0.   0.3  0.   0.   0.01 0.   0.   0.   0.5 ]
 [0.01 0.   0.02 0.   0.   0.01 0.   0.   0.85 0.   0.   0.   0.11]
 [0.03 0.   0.95 0.   0.   0.3  0.   0.   0.3  0.   0.   0.   0.02]]
```

i.e a column with all 0. is added after the first column, two columns with all 0. are added after the second entry and so on, per above.

I have tried the following:

```
pred_galactic_prob2 = np.array
for i in pred_galactic_prob:
    pred_galactic_prob2 = np.append(pred_galactic_prob2, [i[0], 0.0, i[1], 0.0, 0.0, i[2], 0.0, 0.0, i[3], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, i[4]])
```

but this just turns it into a 1D array.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a `np.zeros((405,13))` array, and copying the `pred_galactic_prob` columns to it at the right indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "one-line" solution would be

```
np.concatenate((a[:,:1],
                np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(0,[len(a),1],[0,0]),
                a[:,1:2],
                np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(0,[len(a),2],[0,0]),
                a[:,2:3],
                np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(0,[len(a),2],[0,0]),
                a[:,3:4],
                np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(0,[len(a),3],[0,0]),
                a[:,4:]), -1)
```

Though its wired in any sense. Using `append` would need even more `as_strided`s. I believe there should be a `append`-ish function that automatically broadcasts input but I'm not sure what is it. Anyway, a better solution is definitely as @hpaulj mentioned:

```
b = np.zeros((len(a), 13), a.dtype)
b[:,[0,2,5,8,12]] = a
```

here `a` means input, `b` means output